# How do I change the order of my boxplots in ggplot using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, graphics, boxplot

[image]I am trying to make my two boxplots switch places, `Any_Enrichment` to the right and `Any_Enrichment_Control` to the left.

I'm sure its super trivial but I could not figure out how its done with the right syntax.

My boxplot:

```
data3 %>% 
  dplyr::select(Any_Enrichment, Any_Enrichment_Control) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= Variable, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom= "errorbar", width= 0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(fill=c("#fa9d5a", "cadetblue3"))+
  labs(x="", y="Frequency (total)", title="Stay on enclosure site - Any enrichment")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size =16))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size =16))+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size = 17))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13, color="black"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = 1.5))+
  theme(axis.title.y =element_text(vjust = 2))+
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "errorbar", aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..),
               width = .75,lwd = 0.5, linetype = "dashed", col = "red") +
  #scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Enrichment absent", "Enrichment present"))+
  ylim(0,30)
```

I'm very new to R and any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: by your "boxplots" do you mean the positions of the individual boxes within the plot? (I expected this would be about faceted plots, but I don't see any `facet_*` calls in here ...). The answer is **probably** to adjust the order of levels of a factor.

Comment: As Ben Bolker suggested, reordering the levels of the group factor should do the trick, and you can conveniently do so with package {forcats}. Insert the following somewhere between `pivot_longer` and `ggplot`: `mutate(Variable= forcats::fct_relevel(Variable, c("Enrichment absent", "Enrichment present")))`

Comment: @BenBolker I edited my question, hope that clears it up

Comment: @I_O thanks for your suggestion, however this gives me the error: `Error in fortify():
! data must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by fortify(), not a <uneval> object.
ℹ Did you accidentally pass aes() to the data argument?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the order of items (e.g. boxplots) along a discrete scale in ggplot, you can relevel/reorder the factor underlying the axis. While this can be done in base R, {[forcats](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/)} offers a number of helpers for convenient factor manipulation.

Example, using forcats:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

## your sample data, pivoted into long format:
d <- structure(list(Any_Enrichment = c(0L, 30L, 30L, 28L, 4L, 12L),
                    Any_Enrichment_Control = c(16L, 9L, 30L, 18L, 30L, 3L)),
               row.names = c(NA,  6L),
               class = "data.frame") 


d <- d |>
    pivot_longer(contains('Enrichment'),
                 names_to = 'Treatment', values_to = 'Value'
                 )
```

```
library(ggplot2)

## boxplots in default alphanumeric order 
d |>
    ggplot(aes(Treatment, Value)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image: boxplots in default order]

```
library(forcats)

## boxplots after `relevel`ing Treatment
d |>
    mutate(Treatment = fct_relevel(Treatment,
                                   c('Any_Enrichment_Control', 'Any_Enrichment')
                                   )
           ) |>
    ggplot(aes(Treatment, Value)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image: boxplots after releveling]

Comment: Thank you @I_O ! However I don't know how to code it with `data.frame` :( could you help me on how this is done with my code?

Comment: N3st0r, in that case (and generally) you'd need to provide some sample data to reproduce the problem. You can do that by pasting the output of `dput`ing your structure (or rather a sufficiently small part) like `data3 %>% dplyr::select(Any_Enrichment, Any_Enrichment_Control) %>% head %>% dput`.

Comment: thanks for this info and the respective code, this is the give out: `structure(list(Any_Enrichment = c(0L, 30L, 30L, 28L, 4L, 12L), 
    Any_Enrichment_Control = c(16L, 9L, 30L, 18L, 30L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")` - I hope this is any helpful for you

Comment: see edited version, please